# Помогите с заданием про указатели C++

Tags: c++, c, указатели

```
int main()
{
    char *c[] = {"ENTER", "NEW", "POINT", "FIRST"};
    char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
    char ***cpp = cp;
    printf("%s", **++cpp);
    printf("%s", *--*++cpp+3);
    printf(" %s", *cpp[-2]+3);
    printf("%s", cpp[-1][-1]+1);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста почему вывод: POINTER STEW

На уроке не объяснили толком ничего про указатели, ни инкремент, ни дикремент.
Также не понимаю почему код `printf("%s", *(c+1));` компилится, а
`printf("%s", *++c);` не компилится.

Comment: Ужасы какие у вас на уроках

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//массив указателей на строковые константы
char *c[] = {"ENTER", "NEW", "POINT", "FIRST"};
char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c}; //первый элемент c+3, 
// т.е. мы идем три раза вперед на размерность с и попадаем на POINT
char ***cpp = cp; //ехал указатель через указатель, 
// видит в реке указатель,
// сунул указатель в указатель,
// гитлер гитлер гитлер гитлер  
printf("%s", **++cpp); //выводится POINT
printf("%s", *--*++cpp+3); //снова шастаем по указателям,
// приходим на ENTER, прыгаем на 3 размера данного указателя вперед
// (теперь это char жизнь, сынок, это просто, как ездить на велосипеде,
// и мы в аду и ты горишь и велосипед горит) 
// вместо ENTER получаем ER (ENT ER)
// выводится в итоге POINTER
```

дальше сам понимаешь.

И да, ужасы у вас какие на уроках.

когда кто-нибудь посмотрит в этот ужасный пример и более подробно разберет, с радостью удалю ответ, мне главное чтобы ОП бритвой по венам не прошелся.

[тут](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/102584-array-pointers-confusion.html) намек на решение, спасибо за хороший пример, pointer stew гуглится на ура, задача из книги "[The C Puzzle Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201604612)"

p.s. Pointer stew переводится как  (густой)суп (похлебка, тушеный) указатели. Cуп из указателей. Красиво.

Comment: *--*++cpp+3 не совсем понял как тут вообще попали на Enter

Comment: из-за pre-increment оператора, (++перменная, а не переменная++), он сначала увеличивает значение и возвращает его в выражение, я бы вам рекомендовал кстати взять таблицу приоритетов операторов и расставить скобки, чтобы легче понимать пример http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: скорее всего у вас задание именно на тему понимания очередности операторов и в какую сторону они работают (слева направо или справа налево)

Comment: @j6wj1997 У вас после `++cpp` в предыдущей строке `cpp` указывает на строку `cp[2]`, т.е. "NEW". Потом выполняется `++cpp`, и он становится указывающим на строку `cp[3]`, т.е. "ENTER".

Answer (score 5):

По второй части вопроса:

> Также не понимаю почему код printf("%s", *(c+1)); компилится, а
>   printf("%s", *++c); не компилится.

Потому что `++c` изменяет само значение `c`, а его менять нельзя - `c` - это массив (да, фактически это указатель на первый элемент массива, но таковы правила игры).

Comment: Не совсем так: префиксный `++` для встроенного типа ожидает `lvalue`, выражение `c` является `rvalue`, отсюда и невозможность компиляции этого примера.

Comment: @ixSci Откровенно говоря, решил скрыть это в "правилах игры", потому что тогда надо пояснять, что такое lvalue и rvalue, и, собственно, возвращаться к тому, с чего начали - почему `c` является rvalue...

Comment: тоже верно, просто для более продвинутых пользователей можно было бы расписать, наверное.

Comment: @ixSci согласно сишному Стандарту : `An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially designates an object;`. Т.е. `c` - это `lvalue`. А вот дальше уже сказано про `modifiable lvalue` : `A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type ...`.

Comment: @alexolut, Вы найдите часть, что посвящена массивам и посмотрите, чем является выражение, содержащие имя массива.

Comment: @ixSci, если не сложно, дайте сноску на пункт, т.к. в сишном Стандарте (C11) например про `rvalue` вообще упоминание только в одном месте и то это сноска.

Comment: @alexolut, я бегло просмотрел, но не нашёл. Искать тщательнее — нет времени. Возможно Сишный стандарт явно этого и не говорит, но в C++ есть точно, про преобразование имени массива в указатель. Судя по тому, что делает стандарт С, они просто везде прописывают массив как исключение из правил и избегают использования слова rvalue

Comment: @ixSci просто текущий вопрос по факту к [tag:c++] не относится вовсе. Ибо чистый [tag:c], особенно со строковыми литералами без `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Выполнение префиксных инкрементов/декркментов и разыменоаний указателей происходит от названия переменной в левую сторону, причем запись А[i] равносильна *(A+i), поэтому без дополнительных круглых скобок обращение к элементу массива через квадратные скобки будет выполняться первым. И по этой же причине абсолютно валидна запись i[A], можете попробовать написать так на контрольной :D

а теперь перейдем к вашему коду:

`printf("%s", **++cpp);` указатель срр увеличивается на 1, и указывает на с+2, с+2 это элемент массива с с индексом 2 (помним, что отсчет идет с нуля) разыменовываем его двумя звездочками, и получаем строку "POINT".

`printf("%s", *--*++cpp+3);` здесь срр снова увеличивается на 1, и начинает указывать на с+1, далее разыменовываем его 1 раз, теперь наш кусок выражения указывает на "NEW" уже в самом массиве с(массив ср содержит лишь копии указателей на разные части с), полученный с+1 декрементируем, получаем с, разыменовываем еще раз, получаем строку "ENTER", и лишь теперь выполняется прибавление к этой строке(то есть к указателю на ее нулевой элемент) тройки, то есть начало строки сдвигается на 3 и получается "ER"

`printf(" %s", *cpp[-2]+3);` сначала выполняется обращение к срр[-2], то есть был с+1, стал с+3 и при этом произошло разыменование на один уровень, срр[-2] равносильно *(срр-2), разыменовываем еще раз, получаем строку "FIRST", сдвигаем ее начало на 3 символа и получаем "ST"

`printf("%s", cpp[-1][-1]+1);` помним, что срр все еще равен с+1, и далее первые скобки дают нам с+2, а вторые дают нам строку "NEW", увеличиваем ее начало на 1, и получается "EW".